# ¿Atajo de teclado para comentar un párrafo?

Tags: eclipse

¿Sabe alguien si existe algún atajo de teclado con el que se pueda cambiar a comentario un párrafo que esté seleccionado? A veces se hace un poco tedioso tener que poner los símbolos: "/*" y "*/" al  principio y al final de cada párrafo que quiero "eliminar" temporalmente.
Tampoco sé si este atajo cambia el función del IDE que se utilice. Yo uso Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este enlace puedes encontrar los diferentes atajos que eclipse posee CTRL+/ para comentar CTRL + SHIFT + / para descomentar.

[https://decodigo.com/2012/09/eclipse-accesos-directos.html#:~:text=Ctrl%20%2B%20%2F%20para%20comentar%2C%20o,l%C3%ADneas%20con%20bloques%20de%20comentarios](https://decodigo.com/2012/09/eclipse-accesos-directos.html#:%7E:text=Ctrl%20%2B%20%2F%20para%20comentar%2C%20o,l%C3%ADneas%20con%20bloques%20de%20comentarios).